# Localhost vs cname give different results

Tags: scala, playframework

I have play 2.4 app with following logger.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %p [%c{0}] - &lt;%m&gt;%n%ex</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

When I do request from local machine

`curl http://localhost:9000/`

it executes and access filter logged fine.

```
object AccessLoggingFilter extends Filter {
  val logger: Logger = Logger(this.getClass)

  override def apply(nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
      val requestTime = System.currentTimeMillis - startTime

      logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")
      result
    }
  }
}
```

but via cname:
`curl http://mycname.com/`

I see page but no any logged entry. also some routes don't work via cname ( i see play errors but they are also don't logged).

Is it logger misconfiguration or smth else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that this is ops configuration problem. cname lead to old version of app when i was looking at new version. so logging is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a port number in your 2nd curl invocation:

`curl http://mycname.com:9000/`

Comment: App is responding to requests, so routing from cname:80 port to machine:9000 is configurated.  http://mycname.com/ - return results. but not logged. also some other routes, e.g.  http://mycname.com/rest throw exception.

Comment: Do you get the same output from the 2 different curl invocations?